# Formulário de comentários não aparece no tema

Tags: php, wordpress, formulário, wordpress-theme, comentários

Estou criando um novo tema para WordPress e não consigo fazer aparecer o formulário de comentários do arquivo `comments.php`. Os outros elementos relacionados (comentários já salvos, quantidade de comentários, etc.) aparecem normalmente, mas o formulário em si não aparece mesmo eu deixando os comentários abertos normalmente no *blog*.

O código é este:

```
<?php
   if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
   die ('Por favor não carregue esta página diretamente. Valeu!');

   if (post_password_required()) { ?>
       <p class="nocomments">Este artigo está protegido por senha.</p>
   <?php
       return;
   }
?>
<div class="comentarios row post-texto">
    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <ul class="commentlist">
            <?php wp_list_comments('avatar_size=64&type=comment'); ?>
        </ul>
        <?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
            <div class="pagination">
                <ul>
                    <li class="older"><?php previous_comments_link('Anteriores'); ?></li>
                    <li class="newer"><?php next_comments_link('Novos'); ?></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- Caixa de Comentários -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
        <form name="comment" id="formcomentario" method="POST" action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php">
            <?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>
            <div class="small-12 columns">
            <h5><?php comments_number('Seja o primeiro a comentar!', '1 Comentário. Participe da discussão!', '% Comentários. Participe da discussão!' );?></h5>
            <p>Autenticado como <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo $user_identity; ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" title="Encerrar sessão">[ENCERRAR SESSÃO]</a></p>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <label>Seu nome (obrigatório)
                <input class="comentario-nome" type="text" value="<?php echo $comment_author; ?>" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 columns">
            <label>Seu e-mail (obrigatório)
                <input class="comentario-email" type="text" value="<?php echo $comment_author; ?>" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 columns">
            <label>Seu site (caso haja)
                <input class="comentario-url" type="text" value="<?php echo $comment_author_url; ?>" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <label>Seu comentário
                <textarea class="comentario-texto"></textarea>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <a href="#" class="button expand botao-comentario">Enviar comentário</a>
        </div>
        <?php comment_id_fields(); ?>
        <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
    </form>
    <p><?php cancel_comment_reply_link('Cancelar resposta'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>Os comentários estão fechados.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Qual a causa desse problema?

Comment: vc já verificou se nas configurações no painel esta habilitada a opção de comentário.
caso não fez faça Configurações >> Discussão >> selecione o checkbox de comentarios configurações.

Comment: @Gabriel Essa opção já está ativada na minha instalação do WordPress. Até desativei e reativei pra confirmar e os comentários continuam não aparecendo.

Também ativei e desativei individualmente pro post que estou usando pra testar e nada aconteceu.

Comment: Consegui resolver. Resolvi não escrever mais o formulário na mão e utilizar `<?php comment_form(); ?>`